# Optimization over images of column-orthogonal matrices through rotations and reflections

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, determinant, orthogonal-matrices

The sets of orthogonal matrices with determinant +1 ("rotations") and -1 ("reflections"), respectively, make up distinct sets, so that if we label the sets $R$ and $M$, minimizing

$$
\min_{O\in R}\|O^*-O\|,\quad O^*\in M
$$
will generally lead to a poor approximation, as the sets are disjoint.

Now assume that $X$ is column-orthogonal and rectangular. $OX$ will likewise be column-orthogonal for both $O\in R$ and $O\in M$. The idea of a determinant is no longer applicable (as $X$ is rectangular), so for a column-orthogonal $X^*$, is it possible to simultaneously solve
$$
\min_{O\in M}\|X^*-OX_M\|,
$$
and
$$
\min_{O\in R}\|X^*-OX_R\|
$$
for fixed column-orthogonal matrices $X_M$ and $X_R$? Can an arbitrary column-orthogonal matrix $Y^*$ be written as the reflection/rotation of an arbitrary column-orthogonal matrix, or do we need to impose conditions on $X$? Are the same sets of column-orthogonal matrices reachable?

Comment: "column-orthogonal' means what, exactly? and which matrix norm are you using?

Comment: Column-orthogonal means that the columns are orthogonal, i.e. $X^TX=I$, but $XX^T\neq I$. Perhaps the more salient feature is that $X$ can be rectangular, which is why I say the determinant is no longer applicable.
I'd be interested in hearing results for any norm, thus I left it a bit vague, but if you want a more precisely specified question, I'd be most interested in hearing results for the Frobenius norm.